# C# fastest way to remove duplicates from string: Split vs. Loop

Tags: c#, performance, loops, split, duplicates

I have a string of dash-separated numbers that I am removing duplicate numbers from

```
    string original = "45-1-3-45-10-3-15";
    string new = "45-1-3-10-15";
```

I have tried two approaches, and used Stopwatch to determine which method is faster, but I am getting inconsistent time elapses so I was hoping for some insight into which method would be more efficient for achieving the new duplicate-free list.

Method 1: While loop

```
        List<string> temp = new List<string>();
        bool moreNumbers = true;

        while (moreNumbers)
        {
            if (original.Contains("-"))
            {
                string number = original.Substring(0, original.IndexOf("-"));

                //don't add if the number is already in the list
                int index = temp.FindIndex(item => item == number);
                if (index < 0)
                    temp.Add(value);

                original = original.Substring(original.IndexOf("-") + 1);
            }
            else
                moreNumbers = false;
        }

        //add remaining value in
        string lastNumber = original;

        //don't add if the number is already in the list
        int indexLast = temp.FindIndex(item => item == lastNumber);
        if (indexLast < 0)
            temp.Add(lastNumber);

        string new = "";
        foreach (string number in temp)
        {
            new += "-" + number;
        }
        if (new[0] == '-')
            new = new.Substring(1);
```

Method 2: Split

```
    List<string> temp = original.Split('-').Distinct().ToList();
    string new = "";
    foreach (string number in temp)
    {
         new += "-" + number;
    }
    if (new[0] == '-')
            new = new.Substring(1);
```

I think the second method is more readable, but possibly slower? Which of these methods would be more efficient or a better approach?

Comment: Measure it. Use [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)

Comment: @Habib I did use stopwatch, and like I said the results are being inconsistent -- sometimes method1 measures faster and sometimes method2. Just wondering which of these would be the preferred method

Comment: [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Did you do a warmup, in release build and launching without the debugger attached? And by the way, you can use `string.Join` to rebuild your string instead of the `foreach` + `if` at the end of both methods.

Comment: @suhMAN, Missed the part where you mentioned `Stopwatch` in your question. You should test with a larger data set. Much larger than the one you have in your question.

Comment: You can write method 2 a bit simpler: `string.Join("-", original.Split('-').Distinct());`

Comment: @suhMAN To get consistent results in measuring code, you need to run it N number of times and take the average of the result. 1 million is a good number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be highly optimized but you test for performance.

```
string result = string.Join("-", original.Split('-').Distinct());
```

You have some inefficiencies in both your examples.

Method 1: manipulating a `string` is never efficient. Strings are immutable.

Method 2: no need to create a `List` and use a `StringBuilder()` instead of using string concatenation.

Lastly, `new` is a C# reserved word so none of your code will compile.

Comment: I +1'ed even though this doesn't answer the question at all, readability is probably worth a lot more than the *likely* insignificant performance difference.

Comment: This should have better performance than both solutions presented in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In the first approach, you're using several Substring calls and several IndexOf calls. I don't know exactly the internal implementation, but I guess they are O(n) in time complexity.

Since, for each number in the list, you'll do a full loop in the other list (you're using strings as lists), you'll have an O(n^2) time complexity.

The second option, I assume it is O(n^2) too, because to make a distinct of the list in an IEnumerable, it will have to iterate the list.

I think one optimezed approach to the problem is:

1) loop the main string and for each "-" or end of string, save the number (this will be more economic than the Split in terms of space). 
2) for each number, put it in a Dictionary. This won't be economic in terms of space, but will provide O(1) time to check if the item. Hashing small strings shouldn't be too constly.
3) Loop the Dictionary to retrieve the distinct values.

This implementation will be O(n), better than O(n^2).

Note that only using the dictionary can deliver the result string in a different order. If the order is important, use the Dictionary to check if the item is duplicated, but put in an auxiliary list. Again, this will have a space cost.